# How to find the region of system of nonlinear inequalities?

Tags: inequality

Can someone tell me a numerical method to find the feasible region of system of nonlinear inequalities? I found a method based on Newton Method, but that only finds one point in feasible region. I wan to find the whole region.

Comment: How would a numerical method describe the entire region?

Comment: @ copper.hat: at least a numerical method can find the vertex points of region

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = 1$ has an infinite number of vertices. Unless you know more about the inequalities, I think you are asking for something impossible.